# cdkConnectedOverlay stop positioning after update

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a template:

```
<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="show$ | async"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="{ elementRef: sidebarContainer }"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayPositions]="sidebarPositions"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayHeight]="'100%'"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayFlexibleDimensions]="true"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass]="'not-existing-class'"
  (backdropClick)="close()"
>
```

in package version @angular/cdk@12.2.11, everything works fine but after updating to @angular/cdk@13.1.1 my sidebar can't render to sidebarContainer and render directly to 'body'

What should I do to fix this behaviour or it's some bug in the new version?

Comment: Changing 
`[cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="{ elementRef: sidebarContainer }"`
to
`[cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="sidebarContainer"`

solved the problem